Cockroft-Walton Grounding
I would like to see actual output voltage, so I connected a voltmeter between pins Vout and GND but it shows nothing.
I went through a number of CW circuits and all show grounding. Does that mean I should ground my circuit?


It doesn't work in a simulator, or it doesn't work when you build it?

It works wery well but can't get Voltage readings. Looks like new voltmeter is damaged.

What do you mean by grounding? Your circuit has a ground already so obviously it's not the same as what I would mean.

Could you clarify what voltage your input square wave is? If it's only say, 5V p-p, then your voltmeter should be reading double that. However if you are driving it with hundreds of volts you may have destroyed your voltmeter.

adamssson - Hi, Although you're linking to an off-site image, to comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. Otherwise it looks like you're claiming it's your image. || If the original source is online, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF/video name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + URL). We need you to add the reference link to the source webpage (the existing invisible link direct to the external image isn't enough). TY

In a real, physical circuit, you do not need a ground to make the Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier work.
In a simulator, you must always define a ground point.  That is a requirement for the simulator be able to calculate voltages.
Here's a circuit I made while learning about voltage multipliers:

There's no ground, but the circuit worked perfectly:

LTspice also works correctly, though it does require a ground:

In LTspice, the voltage display measures between the Vout flag and the ground.
In a real circuit, the oscilloscope or voltmeter measures between the points you connect to the probes.


The output of a voltage multiplier is DC.  If you try to measure it with a voltmeter set to AC, then you will read (close to) zero volts.
If you use small value capacitors, then the voltage will "collapse" under the load of your voltmeter.  The impedance of the Cockcroft-Walton depends on the impedance of the capacitors and the frequency of the input AC.  The impedance is multiplied along with the voltage, but it is not linear.  The impedance goes up much faster than the voltage.  After just a few multiplier stages, the impedance is so high that you can't get a usable current out of the multiplier circuit.

